# How GenericContainer from test containers should be parametrised?

Tags: testcontainers

I am getting errors in my IDE about:

> Raw use of parameterized class 'GenericContainer'  Inspection info:
>   Reports any uses of parameterized classes where the type parameters
>   are omitted. Such raw uses of parameterized types are valid in Java,
>   but defeat the purpose of using type parameters, and may mask bugs.

I've checked documentation and creators use everywhere raw type also:
https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_4_quickstart/
f.e.:

```
@Rule
public GenericContainer redis = new GenericContainer<>("redis:5.0.3-alpine")
                                        .withExposedPorts(6379);
```

I dont understand this approach. Can Anyone explain how should I parametrize GenericContainer<>?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Testcontainers uses the self-typing mechanism:

```java
class GenericContainer<SELF extends GenericContainer<SELF>> implements Container<SELF> {
...
}
```

This was a decision to make fluent methods work even if the class is being extended:

```java
class GenericContainer<SELF extends GenericContainer<SELF>> implements Container<SELF> {

    public SELF withExposedPorts(Integer... ports) {
        this.setExposedPorts(newArrayList(ports));
        return self();
    }
}
```

Now, even if there is a child class, it will return the final type, not just `GenericContainer`:

```java
class MyContainer extends GenericContainer< MyContainer> {
}

MyContainer container = new MyContainer()
        .withExposedPorts(12345); // <- without SELF, it would return "GenericContainer"
```

FYI it is scheduled for Testcontainers 2.0 to change the approach, you will find more info in the following presentation:
https://speakerdeck.com/bsideup/geecon-2019-testcontainers-a-year-in-review?slide=74

Comment: Oh. Now I got it. Thanks. 2.0 version is much nicer. Lets wait.

Comment: In fact, you can start doing v2-like already. Code snippets from the slides should work with 1.x

Comment: Can You help me using v2 like api, f.e.: 
`    @ClassRule
    public static final PostgreSQLContainer userDbService = new PostgreSQLContainer<>().withExposedPorts(
            POSTGRESQL_PORT).withNetwork(network).withNetworkAliases("userDbService");`
How To type it to by generic type save? I am getting error `Raw use of parameterized class 'PostgreSQLContainer' `

Comment: this is not an error, but warning (that can be suppressed). v2 will remove the generic type and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 9):

If you declare it like

```
PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(
        "postgres:9.6.12")
        .withDatabaseName("mydb");
```

the warning also goes away.